# Piecewise continuous selection from a correspondence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Take a correspondence $C:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ which is non-empty, convex valued and has closed graph.

For each $x \in [0,1]$ let $a(x) = \{ \max \ y\in C(x), \min \ y \in C(x) \}$ (i.e., the set $a(x)$ contains two points only: the minimum value taken by the correspondence and the maximum). (also remember that $C$ is convex valued).

Now consider $\bigcup_x a(x) $ and assume that this takes up only a finite number of real values.

Is then possible to find a finite set $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\} \subset [0,1]^k$ such that for all $y\in [0,1]$ there exists $x_i$ such that $y \in C(x_i)$?

Note that it is important that the finite set  $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ span the entire range of the correspondence.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Choose any $x$ in $[0,1]$ and let

$$\min C(x)=\alpha_1,\quad\quad \max C(x)=\alpha_2.$$

Note that the minimum and maximum exist because $C(x)$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Since $C(x)$ is convex, we have that for any $0\leq\theta\leq1$

$$\theta \alpha_1+(1-\theta)\alpha_2\in C(x).$$

The above implies that $C(x)$ is the interval $[\alpha_1,\alpha_2]$. In other words, **for any $x$ you pick, $C(x)$ is a closed interval**. Now, suppose that

$$\bigcup_{x\in[0,1]}a(x):=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n\}$$

where $\alpha_1<\alpha_2<\dots<\alpha_n$. There are only $\begin{pmatrix}n \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$ intervals we can form by choosing end points out of $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n\}$, namely

$$[\alpha_1,\alpha_2],[\alpha_1,\alpha_3],\dots,[\alpha_1,\alpha_n],[\alpha_2,\alpha_3],\dots,[\alpha_{n-1},\alpha_{n}].$$

Hence, by picking the $x_i$s such that

$$C(x_1)=[\alpha_1,\alpha_2],\quad C(x_2)=[\alpha_1,\alpha_3],\quad\dots,\quad C\left(x_{(n\text{ choose }2)}\right)=[\alpha_{n-1},\alpha_n],$$

you have your desired set.

ASIDE: By the way, $C:[0,1]\to 2^{[0,1]}$, that is, $C$ maps from $[0,1]$ to the power set of $[0,1]$. If $C:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, then $C$ is a function and not a correspondence (or multivalued function or set-valued function).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get the gist of the proof you suggest. However it is not strictly correct: obviously if for some $y\in [0,1]$ there is no $y$ such that $x \in C(y)$ it is not possible to span $[0,1]$. This is my fault. I suppose your proof would demonstrate the existence of the set for the following question: "Is then possible to find a finite set {x1,…,xn}⊂[0,1]k such that for all $y \in C^{-1}[0,1]$ there exists $x_i$ such that y∈C($x_i$)?"

Comment: Yes, you are right - I misread and assumed that $\cup_{x\in[0,1]} C(x)=[0,1]$. Clearly, if this is not true, there exists some $y\in[0,1]$ such that for any $x\in[0,1]$, $y\not\in C(x)$, never mind $x$ belonging to finite subset of $[0,1]$.